# My computer shows 6 boot options instead of 2

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with my Windows 7 this morning.
The installation was ok but there are 6 choices appearing on my boot options when I boot up.
it was like this:
Ubuntu (blah blah blah... this is the one i choose when I want to boot Ubuntu)
Ubuntu (blah blah blah...)
Check memory
check memory
windows 7 (which I choose to boot windows 7)
windows 7 (blah blah)

Comment: To tell what these boot options are we should know what *"blah blah blah"* is, really. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The other ones are recovery and memory test options. These are useful if something breaks. However, you can modify the GRUB config to not display those options, I don't recommend this though.